# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for SomeLogin

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, tomcat, jaas

Well I'm trying to create JAAS authentication for my Servlet (running on Tomcat 7 in Eclipse), but I'm getting this error.

He're's the complete stack trace:
'`

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
Geg 19, 2013 9:53:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Geg 19, 2013 9:53:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Geg 19, 2013 9:53:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1786 ms
Geg 19, 2013 9:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm authenticate
SEVERE: Unexpected error
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for GdiaLogin
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Geg 19, 2013 10:29:20 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm authenticate
SEVERE: Unexpected error
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for GdiaLogin
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`

In context.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" 
appName="GdiaLogin"
userClassNames="org.ktu.gdia.core.security.UserPrincipal"
roleClassNames="org.ktu.gdia.core.security.RolePrincipal" />
```

In jaas.config (I'm pretty sure Tomcat finds it correctly because I added the correct path with arguments for "run configurations" in eclipse):

```
  GdiaLogin {
    org.ktu.gdia.core.security.GdiaLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

I'm assuming there has to be something wrong with the jaas.config...

My Login Module, not sure if I need to provide it here, though, it's almost straight from a tutorial I've been following:

```
    package org.ktu.gdia.core.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule;

import org.ktu.gdia.core.businesslogic.ControllerFactory;
import org.ktu.gdia.core.interfaces.SecurityControllerInterface;

public class GdiaLoginModule implements LoginModule {

  private CallbackHandler handler;
  private Subject subject;
  private UserPrincipal userPrincipal;
  private RolePrincipal rolePrincipal;
  private String login;
  private List<String> userGroups;

  private SecurityControllerInterface securityController;


  @Override
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
            Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {

      try {

        securityController = ControllerFactory.getInstance().getSecurityController();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to initialize SecurityController in " + this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
    }
      handler = callbackHandler;
      this.subject = subject;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean login() throws LoginException {

    Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
    callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("login");
    callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password", true);

    try {
      handler.handle(callbacks);
      String name = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();
      String password = String.valueOf(((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1])
          .getPassword());

      // Here we validate the credentials against some
      // authentication/authorization provider.
      // It can be a Database, an external LDAP, 
      // a Web Service, etc.
      // For this tutorial we are just checking if 
      // user is "user123" and password is "pass123"

      if (securityController.credentialsValid(name, password)) {

          // TODO authenticate

          login = name;
          userGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
          userGroups.add("admin");
          return true;

      }

      if (name != null &&
          name.equals("user123") &&
          password != null &&
          password.equals("pass123")) {

        // We store the username and roles
        // fetched from the credentials provider
        // to be used later in commit() method.
        // For this tutorial we hard coded the
        // "admin" role
        login = name;
        userGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
        userGroups.add("admin");
        return true;
      }

      // If credentials are NOT OK we throw a LoginException
      throw new LoginException("Authentication failed");

    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
      throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
    }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean commit() throws LoginException {

    userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(login);
    subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);

    if (userGroups != null && userGroups.size() > 0) {
      for (String groupName : userGroups) {
        rolePrincipal = new RolePrincipal(groupName);
        subject.getPrincipals().add(rolePrincipal);
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
    subject.getPrincipals().remove(userPrincipal);
    subject.getPrincipals().remove(rolePrincipal);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Edit: My run configuration arguments in eclipse for tomcat:

```
-Dcatalina.base="D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7" -Dcatalina.home="D:\Servers\GenTreeUploader_Tomcat7" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\Servers\GenTreeUploader_Tomcat7\endorsed" -Djava.security.auth.login.config="D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\conf\jaas.config"
```

Well? Any ideas?

Comment: Where have you placed your context.xml file? It needs to be within the META-INF folder.

Comment: @JamesB It's in the WebContent/META-INF/ folder, along with autogenerated MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JAASRealm

You should set up a login.config file for Java and tell Tomcat where to find it by specifying its location to the JVM, for instance by setting the environment variable: 
`JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jaas.config`

**Added**

For Windows open `startup.bat`
Add the following line: `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config=%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/jaas.config` after `okHome`

e.g.

```
:okHome
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config=%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/jaas.config
set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat"
```

Comment: Well I kind of didn't know where and how to set that environment variable, so I just added it to run configurations, but it does find the jaas.config file I believe, because if I specify wrong path for the config file, it tells me that it can't find the file, right now it doesn't complain about not finding the file. I thought there was something wrong with the inside of the file, but maybe you're right about this one. So can you tell me how I can set it? Is it in Windows, system settings, advanced settings and by adding JAVA_OPTS, or how?

Comment: I don't really get it how to set it, is it JAVA_OPTS as a new environment variable and the value: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config==$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jaas.config"? How will tomcat know to use it then?

Comment: Thanks, I've set the variables, but still seems to throw the same exception somehow. :S

Comment: I would try to run Tomcat without Eclipse (and the modification of the batch file) to understand if the problem in JAAS or not.

Comment: Hi, do you have the settings for startup.sh of Linux version?

Comment: With OSGI bundles this will often happen when you forget to add the jaas.cfg to the build properties

Answer (score 3):

A bit late answer but in case someone is having the same problem enabling their JAAS custom modules within Eclipse: You have to pass the location of jaas.config file to Tomcat in its startup arguments. The way to do it in Eclipse is :

1. Double-click the Tomcat instance on servers tab
2. Click "Open launch configuration"
3. In the "Arguments" tab, there is a VM arguments input text.
4. Append your parameter: -Djava.security.auth.login.config="", i.e:

   -Djava.security.auth.login.config="D:\tomcat\7.0.50"\conf\jaas.config"
5. Click apply, ok and restart server

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem:

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for OwnModule
```

but the path to file jaas.config was right. I am sure, because when I made syntax mistake in jaas.config, I got exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
```

I solved this by **change encoding** file "jaas.config"! First I created this file in UTF-8 and then I got mentioned exception. When I changed encoding to ANSI, it has been running without a problem! A little crazy.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Tomcat 7 running as a service, you cannot use the .bat file (they won't be called).

However, you can run the .EXE Tomcat7w.exe found in the /bin directory. You will see a panel with a Java tab. You can add -D properties (such as pointing to your jaas.config file) there.